# Django error - 'function' object has no attribute 'MyForm'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, backend

I am new to Django and was working with Django forms and stuck at an error for which I am not finding any relevant solution.

My Form.py is :

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

and My views.py is :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from . import forms

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basicapp/index.html')

def forms(request):
    form = forms.MyForm()
    return render(request, 'basicapp/forms.html', context = { 'form' : form 
 })
```

All the routing is Fine as I have checked by replacing forms with a normal HttpResponse but there is some problem in the forms.py or views.py as they the form in not being displayed in the browser and the Error is coming

```
'function' object has no attribute 'MyForm'
```

Please Someone help :( 
I gotta move Forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of the view `def forms(request)` to something else like `def formView()` Your function is calling itself when you do `forms.Myform()`.
 Hence `the 'function' object has no attribute 'MyForm'`